# About radius of convergence

Tags: real-analysis

The question is

Find the radius of convergence of the power series $\sum a_nx^n$ about $x=0$, where $a_n$=$(1+(-1)^{n})/2^n$+ $(1+(-1)^{n-1})/3^n$.

Now what I know about the radius of convergence is that it is the supremum of $1/{a^{1/n}_n}$ and we can derive this formula from Cauchy's root test.

Here $a_n = 2/ 2^n$ if $n$ is even and $a_n= 2/3^n$ if $n$ is odd.

Hence limsup $1/{a^{1/n}_n}$=$3$ . So radius of convergence is also $3$.

But the answer is given $2$. That's why I am getting confused. Am I missing something?

Comment: $\frac{1}{R}=\limsup_{n\to \infty}{|a_n|^{\frac{1}{n}}}.$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the formula of radius wrongly. The radius of convergence is given by $$R = \frac{1}{\limsup_{n\to \infty} |a_n|^{1/n}}.$$

Just notice that $$\limsup_{n\to \infty}|a_n|^{1/n} = \lim_{k\to \infty} \sup_{n\geq k}|a_n|^{1/n} = \lim_{k\to \infty} \sup\left\{\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{3}\right\}  = \lim_{k\to \infty} \frac{1}{2}=\frac{1}{2}.$$

Therefore, $R=2$.